# Python Tkinter Listbox - How to determine if an item was actually selected during mouse event

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

How to find out if an item was actually selected in a tkinter listbox and not just the nearest item?

```
import tkinter as tk

def my_function(item):
    x = listbox.get(item)
    print(f'You chose: {x}')

root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(720, 480)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

listbox = tk.Listbox(root, selectmode='single')
listbox.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='news')

label = tk.Label(root, text='<-- If you right-click inside the listbox way down here, you still highlight the last item. I dont want it to select any item unless you actually click on the item.', wraplength='400', font='Verdana 18')
label.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='s')

my_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
for i in my_list:
    listbox.insert('end', i)

def popupmenu(event):
    # CLEAR SELECTION
    listbox.selection_clear(0, 'end')

    # HIGHLIGHT THE EXACT ITEM IN LISTBOX WHERE USER RIGHT-CLICKED AT AND NOT JUST THE NEAREST ITEM ??
    listbox.selection_set(listbox.nearest(event.y))

    # TODO: if an item exists in listbox at event.x, event.y location somehow?....

    # CURRENTLY SELECTED ITEM
    item = listbox.curselection()

    # POPUP MENU
    popup_menu = tk.Menu(root, tearoff=0)
    popup_menu.add_command(label='My Function', command=lambda: my_function(item))
    popup_menu.add_separator()
    popup_menu.add_command(label='Quit', command=root.destroy)
    try:
        # SHOW POPUP MENU
        popup_menu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    finally:
        # CLOSE POPUP MENU
        popup_menu.grab_release()

listbox.bind('<Button-3>', popupmenu)

root.mainloop()
```

I want it so that when you right-click inside the listbox, it only highlights an item if the mouse actually clicked an item, instead of it just highlighting the nearest item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the item nearest the mouse pointer by using an index of the form *@x,y*. You can get the bounding box (x, y, width, height) for that index, and then check that the y coordinate of the event is inside that bounding box.

For example:

```
x, y, width, height = listbox.bbox(f"@{event.x},{event.y}")
if y <= event.y <= y + height:
    print("you're over an item")
else:
    print("you are not over an item")
    return
```